# Python & BS4: Exclude blank and Grand Total Row

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, repeat

Below is my code to extract data out of an HTML document and place it into variables.  I need to exclude the blank lines, as well as the "grand total" line.  I've added the HTML input of those segments beneath my code.  I'm not sure how to make it work.  I can't use `len()` because the length is variable.  Any help?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import re
import HTMLParser
html = urllib.urlopen('RanpakAllocations.html').read()
parser = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
#unescape doesn't seem to work
output = parser.unescape(html)

soup1 = BeautifulSoup(output, "html.parser")
Customer_No = []
Serial_No = []
data = []
#for hit in soup.findAll(attrs={'class' : 'MYCLASS'}):
rows = soup1.find_all("tr")
title = rows[0]
headers = rows[1]
datarows = rows[2:]

fields = []

try :
    for row in datarows :
        find_data = row.find_all(attrs={'face' : 'Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif'})
        count = 0
        for hit in find_data:
            data = hit.text
            count = count + 1
            if count == 3 :
                CSNO = data
            if count == 9 :
                ITNO = data
            else :
                continue

        print CSNO, ITNO
        print "new row"
except:
    pass
```

Here is the input. The first `<tr>` is my last row of data, however my loop is repeating for the blank rows and the grand total row below it.

```
<tr>
        <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">12</font></td>
        <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">F5684</font></td>
        <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">20182</font></td>
        <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">VELOCITY SOLUTIONS INC.</font></td>
        <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">EQPRAN77717</font></td>
        <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">RANPAK FILLPAK TT 2</font></td>
        <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">W/UNIVERSAL STAND S/N 51345563</font></td>
        <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">1</font></td>
        <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">51345563</font></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><font size="1">&nbsp;</font></td>
        <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><font size="1">&nbsp;</font></td>
        <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><font size="1">&nbsp;</font></td>
        <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><font size="1">&nbsp;</font></td>
        <td align="left" colspan="5"><font size="1">&nbsp;</font></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="left"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">&nbsp;</font></td>
        <td align="left"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">Grand Total</font></td>
        <td align="left" colspan="7"><font size="1">&nbsp;</font></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
```

Comment: I can't see the HTML @AlliDeacon?

Comment: I've added the HTML @lambo477 Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Ok, I've added `if len(find_data) > 0 :` and that's eliminated the blank lines, but I still have the grand total line to work with.  I'm going to try to include that in the range of `datarows`

Comment: Great @AlliDeacon, see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content = '''
<root>
    <tr>
        <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">12</font></td>
        <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">F5684</font></td>
        <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">20182</font></td>
        <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">VELOCITY SOLUTIONS INC.</font></td>
        <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">EQPRAN77717</font></td>
        <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">RANPAK FILLPAK TT 2</font></td>
        <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">W/UNIVERSAL STAND S/N 51345563</font></td>
        <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">1</font></td>
        <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">51345563</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><font size="1">&nbsp;</font></td>
        <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><font size="1">&nbsp;</font></td>
        <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><font size="1">&nbsp;</font></td>
        <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><font size="1">&nbsp;</font></td>
        <td align="left" colspan="5"><font size="1">&nbsp;</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">&nbsp;</font></td>
        <td align="left"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">Grand Total</font></td>
        <td align="left" colspan="7"><font size="1">&nbsp;</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</root>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html')

answer = []
rows = soup.find_all('tr')

for row in rows:
    if not row.text.strip():
        continue

    row_text = []
    for cell in row.find_all('td'):
        if cell.text.strip():
            row_text.append(cell.text)

    answer.append(row_text)

print(answer)
```

**Output**

```
[[u'12', u'F5684', u'20182', u'VELOCITY SOLUTIONS INC.', u'EQPRAN77717', u'RANPAK FILLPAK TT 2', u'W/UNIVERSAL STAND S/N 51345563', u'1', u'51345563'], [u'Grand Total']]
```

You can skip over entire empty rows using `if not row.text.strip(): continue` (`row.text.strip()` returns an empty string, which evaluates to `False`).

For rows that you do iterate over, you can check each cell is not empty using `if cell.text.strip()` before saving the relevant text.

Comment: This is great!  I ended up using the `len()` and for `datarows` I updated the range to [2:(-3)] and that seemed to work perfect for my needs. I will keep this trick in my pocket though!

Comment: Good stuff - keep up the practice :)